# Key management in corda

Tags: corda

In Corda, while using accounts we request for public keys for performing any kind of transaction and it is advisable to use that public key for one time Or for one transaction. So what will be the max threshold of requesting the public keys for an account.
Or in other words what is the maximum number of public keys we can be generate for an account.

Answer (score 0):

There is no threshold as such. The keys get stored in the database, so as long as you have storage space you should be good.

Comment: What algorithm corda is using for producing these public keys?

Comment: @Karanchopra Confidential Identities https://github.com/corda/confidential-identities/blob/master/docs/OVERVIEW.md

Comment: According to this link corda uses SHA 256, and we can make possible number of request for public key of an account is 2^256. Is it correct?

Comment: It seems so. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49519987/how-many-combinations-does-sha-256-have

Comment: Alessandro so the max number of pk we can get is 2^256 right? But corda is recommending usage of new pk everytime. Also @AshutoshMeher is also saying there is no threshold as such.

Comment: Well, 2^256 is insanely big. You dont have to worry about ever reaching that limit.